# postgreSQL: Sorting when creating XML

Tags: xml, postgresql

I am stuck writing my query to output some XML.

I got a table with a couple of 100ets of entries:

Table dokumentationsschritte(simplified)

dokuschritt_id,vorgang_id,version_pool,version_lokal,typ,vorgang_nummer

My query:

```
SELECT XMLFOREST(tb1."xml-val" AS "dokumentationsschritte") 
FROM 
(SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(NAME dokumentationsschritt ,XMLATTRIBUTES(t.dokuschritt_id AS dokuschritt_id,t.vorgang_id AS vorgang_id,t.version_pool AS version_pool,t.version_lokal AS version_lokal,t.deprecated AS deprecated),
XMLELEMENT(NAME typ,t.typ),XMLELEMENT(NAME dokuschritt_nummer,t.dokuschritt_nummer))) AS  "xml-val" 
FROM dokumentationsschritte t WHERE t.vorgang_id='4930c02e-1457-316c-c11f-9b7d7f1acb85') AS tb1;
```

This works, as I get all entries as XML:

```
<dokumentationsschritte>
  <dokumentationsschritt dokuschritt_id="88942eb7-fbeb-3740-a1b5-a188b0029791" vorgang_id="4930c02e-1457-316c-c11f-9b7d7f1acb85" version_pool="0" version_lokal="3" deprecated="0">
    <typ>1</typ>
    <dokuschritt_nummer>1204</dokuschritt_nummer>
  </dokumentationsschritt>
  <dokumentationsschritt dokuschritt_id="94bdeccf-2c89-3163-bd10-6f4353c8b575" vorgang_id="4930c02e-1457-316c-c11f-9b7d7f1acb85" version_pool="0" version_lokal="3" deprecated="0">
    <typ>1</typ>
    <dokuschritt_nummer>755</dokuschritt_nummer>
  </dokumentationsschritt>
</dokumentationsschritte>
```

but I would like to ORDER BY dokuschritt_nummer

As soon as I add an ORDER BY it errors out asking for a GROUP BY, but if I add that, the XML gets screwed... No more root node, but a dokumentationsschritte node for each entry.

[edit]

```
SELECT XMLFOREST(tb1."xml-val" AS "dokumentationsschritte") 
FROM 
(SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(NAME dokumentationsschritt ,XMLATTRIBUTES(t.dokuschritt_id AS dokuschritt_id,t.vorgang_id AS vorgang_id,t.version_pool AS version_pool,t.version_lokal AS version_lokal,t.deprecated AS deprecated),
XMLELEMENT(NAME typ,t.typ),XMLELEMENT(NAME dokuschritt_nummer,t.dokuschritt_nummer GROUP BY dokuschritt_nummer ORDER BY dokuschritt_nummer))) AS  "xml-val" 
FROM dokumentationsschritte t WHERE t.vorgang_id='4930c02e-1457-316c-c11f-9b7d7f1acb85') AS tb1;
```

[/edit]

```
 <dokumentationsschritte><dokumentationsschritt dokuschritt_id="4b57c57a-0330-3dc7-8eed-f1b0192c6372" vorgang_id="4930c02e-1457-316c-c11f-9b7d7f1acb85" version_pool="0" version_lokal="2" deprecated="0"><typ>2</typ><dokuschritt_nummer>1</dokuschritt_nummer></dokumentationsschritt></dokumentationsschritte>
    <dokumentationsschritte><dokumentationsschritt dokuschritt_id="966136b2-5fc3-306c-88db-064e4d17f710" vorgang_id="4930c02e-1457-316c-c11f-9b7d7f1acb85" version_pool="0" version_lokal="1" deprecated="0"><typ>1</typ><dokuschritt_nummer>2</dokuschritt_nummer></dokumentationsschritt></dokumentationsschritte>
```

I am pretty much lost. Can you help?

Thanks a lot!

Malte

Comment: You didn't show your code attempt for `ORDER BY`.

Comment: True. Sorry for that: Edited original post

Comment: And could you make an example on sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to sqlfiddle! Did not know that site. I made a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3b4d2 but the query will not run at all there. :-(

Comment: Yes, it's unusual this doesn't work. But I got the data I needed to test the query locally as I wasn't quite sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, if you want the data inside the aggregate function to be sorted you have to place the `ORDER BY` inside the agg([[ref]](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)).

```
SELECT XMLFOREST(tb1."xml-val" AS "dokumentationsschritte") 
FROM 
(SELECT XMLAGG(
               XMLELEMENT(NAME dokumentationsschritt 
                          ,XMLATTRIBUTES(t.dokuschritt_id AS dokuschritt_id,t.vorgang_id AS vorgang_id,t.version_pool AS version_pool,t.version_lokal AS version_lokal,t.deprecated AS deprecated)
                          ,XMLELEMENT(NAME typ,t.typ)
                          ,XMLELEMENT(NAME dokuschritt_nummer,t.dokuschritt_nummer)                          
                          )      
              ORDER BY dokuschritt_nummer        
              ) AS  "xml-val" 
FROM 
dokumentationsschritte t
WHERE t.vorgang_id='4930c02e-1457-316c-c11f-9b7d7f1acb85') AS tb1;
```